# Copy multiple files in a folder and lines into one masterfile

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I am new at creating macros. Only created 5 of them for specific problems.

Could someone help me amend the below macro? I found it on the internet, I amended it to my preferences. But still there is room from improvement. Anyways it works perfectly except for the below.

There would be a lot of files in folder. Each file contains a tab named "PIVOT", where the format are the same, but the amount of data are different.

The range is in the PIVOT tab are from A to AM columns. They start at row 15. And I would only need those lines where the "closed" indication is not written (Status column is in AJ column). I want all of these rows to be copied into a master file under each other. The amount of rows varies greatly - like 0 to 200 depending on the open items.

Secondly, can someone tell me a book, that could be purchased so that I could evolve my knowledge?
Thank For your help!

Tibor

Sub Import_to_Master()
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim wbD As Workbook, wbS As Workbook

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wbS = ThisWorkbook
sFolder = wbS.Path & "\"

sFile = Dir(sFolder)
Do While sFile <> ""

    If sFile <> wbS.Name Then
        Set wbD = Workbooks.Open(sFolder & sFile) 'open the file; add condition to

         ' >>>>>> Adapt this part
        wbD.Sheets("PIVOT").Range("A15:AM26").Copy
        wbS.Activate
        Sheets("Template").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
         ' >>>>>>
        wbD.Close savechanges:=True 'close without saving
    End If

    sFile = Dir 'next file
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Wouldn't worry about a book when you have StackOverflow and the rest of the internet. You have already found the last row in your master with `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)` so you can just modify your `Range("A15:AM26")` using the above code to find the last row in your individual files.

Comment: Ok, but there are lines, which are not needed. I only need those where the status is not closed. There is a specific column with 9-10 option. One of them is "closed", but that is what I don't care.
Plus if I add Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp), it says out of range. I assume it is because the source file starts from row 14.
Thanks for the booking advice :) but I would look for something that teaches me something day by day if I spend 15-30 mins per day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to check each row for a certain cell value use something like the following. This will loop through line by line checking for lines that don't say "Closed".

```
Dim sFolder As String, sFile As String, wbD As Workbook, wbS As Workbook
Dim lastRowS As Integer, lastRowD As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wbS = ThisWorkbook
sFolder = wbS.Path & "\"
sFile = Dir(sFolder

lastRowS = Sheets("Template").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Do While sFile <> ""

If sFile <> wbS.Name Then
    Set wbD = Workbooks.Open(sFolder & sFile) 'open the file; add condition to

    lastRowD = wbD.Sheets("PIVOT").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 15 To lastRowD
        If Cells(i, 3) <> "Closed" Then 'change 3 to whatever column number has Closed in
            wbD.Sheets("PIVOT").Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy
            wbS.Sheets("Template").Cells(lastRowS, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            lastRowS = lastRowS + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
     ' >>>>>>
    wbD.Close savechanges:=False 'close without saving
End If

sFile = Dir 'next file
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It works cool. The only thing which is not working properly, is the "closed" part checker. It gives back everything deleting the previous comments which are not "Closed" regardless of the IF functionality. I tried everything to make it work before I have asked you. :(

Comment: Hello TIm, sorry for not coming back to you. I got sick, then I was tied up with my work. But this is the code I am using in my macro, it works perfectly. 
The other solution is good as well, but my knowledge level is only good for this, so if there is something goes wrong with the other one, I cannot even amend it. But thanks for user3598756 for the help!

Answer (score 1):

you may be after this:

```
        ' >>>>>> Adapted part
        With wbD.Sheets("PIVOT")
            With .Range("AM14", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column "A:AM" range from row 14 down to column "A" last not empty row
                .AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:="<>closed" '<--| filter referenced range on its 36th column (i.e. column "AJ") with values different from "closed"
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then
                    .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                    Sheets("Template").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End If
            End With
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
        ' >>>>>>
```

Comment: This is far better than mine, use this!

Comment: @TimWilkinson, thanks for your _endorsement_!. Actually `AutoFilter()` is much faster then looping through cells.

Comment: Hello user3598756!
I used your coding, but it gives bakc error message saying 400. Everything should be okay in what you posted, I checked the references as well, but cannot figure out what the problem could be.

Comment: And I admire both of your VBA knowledge! Thanks for your helps! How can I endorse both of you here?

Comment: It says only "400" in a popping up window.

Comment: if you click "Debug" button it will bring you to the offending line highlighted in yellow or blue

Comment: Yeah, I ran it in debug mode, line by line, but this is the line where it stops and shows this mysterious "400" error message. The line in questions is:   .AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:="<>closed"
I checked this "400" coding, but no one could explain what this is for. Yeah, it offers me a "help" button, but it leads to an MS office lengthy site.

Comment: after `With .Range("AM14", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))` place the following statement: `MsgBox .Address` and see what it pops out

Comment: It says "&A&14:&AM&26" This is where the data is appearing. Line 14 is the header. Line 26 is a grand total line, so 25 is the last line off the raw data required.

Comment: it says "&A&14:&AM&26" or "$A$14:$AM$26"?

Comment: With dollar sign. So the second.

Comment: substitute the previous `MsgBox` with `MsgBox .Parent.Name` and see the pop out

Comment: Not it says "PIVOT" - it refers to the PIVOT tab from which it is supposed to extract the info.

Comment: _"Not it says "PIVOT"_ means it doesn't pop out "PIVOT" but something else? If so, what does it pop out?

Comment: Sorry, now it says "PIVOT" - slight typo... Only a window popped up telling this.

Comment: substitute the previous MsgBox with MsgBox `.Parent.Parent.Name` and see the pop out